# Multiple rows in group footer/table footer band?

Tags: jasper-reports

[image]

i want to develop jasper template given in image how can i create multiple rows in group footer and in table footer band?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one band gets reprinted multiple times: the detail band.

No other band has this functionality. If you want multiple rows you can:

- hard code them into the band
- use a subreport
- use a table
- use a crosstab

Comment: ohh thanks markus my problem is solved by hard code rows in report template